# C, what does this line do?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I saw this line of code for a topic at codegolf.

```
struct { int (*log)(const char *,...); } console = { printf };
```

This is the original post
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/24623/write-program-in-your-favorite-language-in-another-language
Although i know c/c++, i cannot understand this line.
I thought to create synonyms, you use typefs , so what is this (console={printf}).
Also, i dont understand the struct at all.  Why a struct and what is going on inside... IS this a casting of pointers? What is this ,....  we see inside?

Comment: If you don't recognize a function pointer, a variadic function and an initializer list, then probably you don't "know c/c++". Also, [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org)

Comment: I recognize these elements, but I would never code that way. Never in a million years...

Comment: Whoever wrote that does not "speak C" as their first language.  They are trying to make C look like Java or one of its descendants.

Comment: @wallyk The Code Golf entry was about writing in one language making it look like the other. I'd even guess he is bilingual :)

Comment: This was a Code Golf entry. One should not wonder too much about architecture and readability on these entries. Here he was trying to make this C code look like Java or something else, so of course he has to take a detour from regular C paradigms.

Comment: Synonyms can be written in many ways in `C`:  Using `#define`, pointer aliases, function pointers, and probably one or two more.  There is no type casting there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, let's work from the outside in:

```
struct { T m; } console = { i };
```

You're defining an anonymous struct type with a single member `m` of type `T`, then using that type to declare a variable named `console` and initializing it with an initializer `{ i }`.

So what are `T`, `m`, and `i`?

The member declaration

```
int (*log)(const char *, ...);
```

breaks down as

```
      log                         -- log
    (*log)                        -- is a pointer to
    (*log)(                 )     -- a function
    (*log)(const char *, ...)     -- taking a fixed parameter of type 
                                         const char *, followed by a variable
                                         number of parameters
int (*log)(const char *, ...);    -- returning int
```

So, the member `m` is named `log`, and its type `T` is `int (*)(const char *, ...)`.

The initializer expression is

```
{ printf }
```

The prototype for `printf` is

```
int printf(const char *, ...);
```

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, a function designator of type "function returning `T`" will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to function returning `T`".  Thus, the type of the expression `printf` within the initializer is

```
int (*)(const char *, ...);
```

Look familiar?  That's the same type of the `log` member.

**TL;DR version**

You're creating a struct type containing a single member named `log`, which is used to point to a function like `printf`.  It would be used something like this:

```
struct { int (*log)(const char *, ...); } console = { printf };
...
console.log("%s\n", "This is a test");
```

Answer (score 2):

That is defining and initializing function pointer `log()` initially to `printf` to an item in a structure as its only element.

The prototype is completely compatible with printf.  Use it like this:

```
console.log ("format string %d %d", param1, param2);
```

If at some point during computation, a different actual function should be used as output, the pointer can be reassigned.

```
int myoutputfunction (const char *, ...)
{
    (do something useful here)
}

console.log = myoutputfunction;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct {
    // struct with one member
    // that member is called log
    // accepts one const char *
    // and an arbitrary amount of optional extra arguments
    int (*log)(const char *,...);
}
// declared console variable of type that struct
console = {
    // and initialises its first member to
    printf
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct { int (*log)(const char *,...); } console = { printf };
console.log("abc");
```

is semantically equivalent to:

```
typedef int (*FncPtr)(const char *,...);   // function pointer

typedef struct c {
    FncPtr log;
} Console;                                 // struct holding function pointer

Console console;
console.log = printf;                      // initialization of this pointer
console.log("abc");                        // possible usage
```

which is nothing but one of the possible ways how to make:

```
console.log( /* some parameters */ );
```

to produce exactly same result as:

```
printf( /* some parameters */ );
```

Comment: @CJohnson: Writing too much code to a single line just decreases the readability. It's always good to keep your code clean :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a structure that contains a member that is a pointer to a function returning an int type, and it is being initialized to the address of the printf function.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct { int (*log)(const char *,...); } console = { printf };
```

here `console` is a `variable of struct` that has one member `log`.
struct has a `member that is a pointer to a function` that returns integer and takes as argument a const character string and variable length parameter `...`. 
the assignment creates a `struct variable console` and `console.log` is made to point to `printf()`